# ForYouFragment Fragment doesn't update

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-fragments

Hi i have permission check on my forYou fragment when the app starts start and you give the permission and it makes a api call and get the weather for you current location the problem is I must switch the fragment for getting the call and switch again for showing it in the reclyerview the problem is when I give the permission for the location it doesn't do the api after that, I must refresh the fragment

```
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity()) { location ->
        if (location != null) {
            currentLocation = location
            val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            val currentAddress = getAddress(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            Log.d("TAG", "klagenfurt : ${currentAddress}")
            retrofitOneCallResponse(location.latitude, location.longitude, currentAddress)
            dataService.getFavorites(this)

        }


    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            requireActivity(),
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            MapViewFragment.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
        )

        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one method like this.

```
private fun getLocation(){
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity()) { location ->
        if (location != null) {
            currentLocation = location
            val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            val currentAddress = getAddress(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            Log.d("TAG", "klagenfurt : ${currentAddress}")
            retrofitOneCallResponse(location.latitude, location.longitude, currentAddress)
            dataService.getFavorites(this)
        }else{
         getLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

then from here

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            MapViewFragment.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }else{
      getLocation()
}


override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray): Unit {
      if(requestCode==MapViewFragment.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE){
          if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
              getLocation();
          }
      }
}
```

Also, override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` in the fragment. and check if permission granted the call `getLocation()`.

Comment: I can't write the method getLocation because the fusedLocation needs a permisson check

Comment: try this code pattern then you will see that there will no err at compile since the getLocation is called after checking the condition. Studio will analyze the flow

Comment: i don't understand the onRequestPermissonResult?

Comment: i post a screenshot please look at this, I try it like 3 days now nothing its working

Comment: It was a bug I have fixed it please check now, in fragment call the `requestPermissions` directly so that result will be given to frament otherwise it goes to activity.

Comment: @Sir_Flatcher please remove your question-related information from the answer section.

Comment: the onRequestPermisson is not a override method I can't override ride it, and the  fusedLocationClient.lastLocation. says it needs a permission check like before :/

Comment: I write the premisson check in the geolocation method and call it from one create and it works thank you so much but the second problem I got is that I get the call when I give the permission but this time it doesn't refresh the fragment

Comment: when I switch fragments and come back I can see the current locations weather

Comment: I assume that null received in success, so I have modified it a bit

Comment: no I can see the database inspector it save the favorites but it does only shown when I refresh not instantly

Comment: Well, @Sir_Flatcher I have answered the original question, if you are facing some other issue, then you can ask a new question in this forum. I hope you understand the effort it takes to answer the questions.

Comment: yeah of course thank you anyways for your time !

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT74u.jpg)
HERE it says and you write the code without ActivityCompat on the requestpermisson line it doesn't work etiher